# XAMPP does not recognize php, must replace all <? with <?php

Tags: php, tags, xampp

I am having issues with XAMPP. It does not recognize php correctly. For example:

```
<?php echo "This is working !"; ?>
```

And this isn't:

```
<? echo "L O L"; ?>
```

Using XAMPP v.3.0.12

Comment: Go to `phpini` and enable the use of short tags

Comment: `XAMPP v.3.0.12` is crazy `old` .. update to `1.8.1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to enable `short_open_tag` in php.ini

However, for compatibility reasons with system where you haven't control over the php.ini, I would not use the short open tags.

Comment: This, but it's always best to write your code using `<?php` for compatibility's sake.

Answer (score 3):

That's because XAMPP has php short tags turned off.  That's a good thing, as many enviroments have, as default, the same setting, and some don't let you turn it back on.  But note, as of php 5.4, `<?= ?>` tags don't count as short tags, and can be used while short tags are turned off.

Answer (score 2):

In your php.ini there is an option for allow short tags just turn it on. It will work i.e

```
short_open_tag =  on
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do changes in php.ini file

```
short_open_tag = on
```

**NOTE** : Don't use short tag, It will depreciate in PHP 6

Comment: short tags were never deprecated, not even on 7.0, and it is actually moving closer to being default